# TToolButton Indeterminate state set to true by Delphi? (grays images)

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-xe4

I have discovered a weird issue with my Delphi XE4 program. I have a toolbar with some toolbuttons. They also have a dropdown. I have code like this:

```
  m_View_SideColumns.Enabled := TmpOptionEnabled_View_SideColumns;
  tb_View_Columns.Indeterminate := False;
  tb_View_Columns.Enabled := TmpOptionEnabled_View_SideColumns;
  {$IFDEF mymsDELPHI}
  tb_View_Columns.EnableDropDown := TmpOptionEnabled_View_SideColumns;
  {$ENDIF}
```

**(The above is just one of multiple similar toolbuttons)**

The above code is called ether explicitly on changes or when app is idle somehow.

What I have found is that sometimes `Indeterminate` is true...

I don't have code setting it true, so I think it is something that happens deep inside Delphi handling my toolbar with toolbuttons...

**Update #1**

Also worth noting. I first saw this issue after adding manifest support for Windows 10 ... So maybe related since I have otherwise been using my software for 10 years across Windows versions without ever noticing his issue.

Could also be a Windows 10 update changed something.

**Update #2**

Seems related to clicking toolbarbuttons/dropdowns and the *EnableDropDown* setting.

If I do not touch EnableDropDown (setting it to true) problem does not happen when clicking buttons...

Comment: This is a property with a setter procedure, you can place a breakpoint in `procedure TToolButton.SetIndeterminate(Value: Boolean);` to catch the moment the porperties value changes.

Comment: Do you really mean that the value of the `Indeterminate` property is sometimes `True` - like observed in debugger? There might be situations where the button's state might look the same without the property being `True`:   `if (FIndeterminate or FEnableDropdown) then
    Result := Result or ButtonStates[tbsIndeterminate];`

Comment: @nil yes observed in debugger. I have found a few other posts on the net describing the same problem - bu very few and very old

Comment: @nil Just for reference - breakpoint at SetIndeterminate did not help. It it not what sets it true. I can see the underlying FIndeterminate is also set anoher palce which would indicate possibly windows API is setting a flag

Comment: I believe that `EnableDropDown` might be a bit confusing - and might have an issue because of this - as it is using the WinAPI's `TBSTATE_INDETERMINATE` to keep the button responsive to allow the dropdown to work while having the button look disabled. If `EnableDropDown` is `True` the assumption seems to be that `Enabled` is `False`. I hope you understand what I mean.